# Generic array constructor

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Here's my code that converts a Json to a class of my own:

```
JSONArray boats = p["data"]["game"]["start"]["boats"].AsArray;
j.data.game.start.boats = new JsonGameDetailBoat[boats.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < boats.Count; i++) {
    JSONNode boat = boats[i];
    j.data.game.start.boats[i] = new JsonGameDetailBoat {
        name = boat["name"],
        total = boat["total"]
    };
}
JSONArray board = p["data"]["game"]["board"].AsArray;
j.data.game.board = new JsonGameDataCell[board.Count][];
for (int i = 0; i < board.Count; i++) {
    /* almost same code than previous loop */
}
```

Watch the last lines: I have to make another loop, to make the same thing.

And I'll have to do this 4 more times.

So I'm trying to make a generic that would convert a JSONArray to a custom class, and fetch each properties of  as string and read them from the JSON array.

My code looks like this but it doesn't work, and I dont know if it's possible to enumerate the public properties of a class.

```
public class JSONArrayConverter<T>
{
    public JSONArrayConverter(JSONNode p)
    {
        JSONArray tab = p.AsArray;
        IList<T> result;
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Count; i++) {
            JSONNode value = tab[i];
            result[i] = new <T>();
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work, I'm stuck here: `result[i] = new <T>();`

Comment: Two things. 1) `new List<T>()` and 2) you need to specify `T`

Comment: Three things: 3) `result` is the list, you need to set `result` to the list, not one element of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection

```
public JSONArrayConverter(JSONNode p)
{
    JSONArray tab = p.AsArray;
    IList<T> result = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.Count(); i++)
    {
        JSONNode value = tab[i];
        result[i] = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), value);
    }
}
```

or an interface:

```
public interface JSONConvertable
{
    void Initialise(JSONNode node);
}

public class JSONArrayConverter<T> where T : JSONConvertable, new()
{
    public JSONArrayConverter(JSONNode p)
    {
        JSONArray tab = p.AsArray;
        IList<T> result = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Count(); i++)
        {
            JSONNode value = tab[i];
            result[i] = new T();
            result[i].Initialise(value);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

**Or callback**

```
public JSONArrayConverter(JSONNode p, Func<JSONNode, T> creator)
{
    JSONArray tab = p.AsArray;
    IList<T> result = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.Count(); i++)
    {
        JSONNode value = tab[i];
        result[i] = creator(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not generic because you precise the keys `"name"`, and `"total"` I'd like to make a loop on the properties of the class `<T>`

Comment: Well, you could just have value as a parameter

Comment: I wouldn't want to loop on the properties, let the class handle it itself. Using reflection would be messy, and really slow

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to make a callback (= delegate) that would create a `<T>` type then assign the properties, and return the newly `<T>` type. This delegate declaration doesnt work `private delegate <T> CallbackAfterWaitMessage();` how should I write this?

Comment: Your problem is, that you are using T as <T>. the <, > symbols are just used to specifie a generic type, you use the T as the type.